# Creating an AutoHotKey script for "left-click and hold" by clicking left button and holding it down 5 seconds

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking for help in creating an AutoHotKey script so that when I click the left button of my mouse and hold it down for 5 seconds, it triggers a "click-and-hold" action until I click it again to release. If it's not possible by holding it down 5 seconds, then perhaps by clicking it 3 times in a row?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you mind sharing?

Answer (score 0):

I would say either way is possible.  Have you looked into

**KeyWait** at

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm

and/or

**GetKeyState** at

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm

and the examples in there yet?

In the first scenario, after detecting mouse down, you check again 5 seconds later to see if it is still down, or immediately return upon a mouse up (before the 5 secs are elapsed).

In the second scenario, you do multiple keywaits (the example does a double click, but just add to it one more level to detect three clicks).

Btw, if you show us your code so far, we can help with specific issues you may have getting it to work since it is a bit tricky.

Hth,

Comment: Thank you for replying. I do not have a script yet as I just found out about AutoHotKey, but did not know how it worked at all. I'm guessing I install it and it has a dashboard to create scripts? 
Is it a complicated script to make (the KeyWait one)?

Comment: Also, I'm sure it's NOT as easy as this, right?
~LButton::
KeyWait, LButton, D T5
Click, D